# How to plot bar stack in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

The objective is to plot a bar that stack as shown below using the Pandas builtin plot module

[image: Expected Output]

However, I cannot find any near example that tried to achieve similar objective.

The sample code that I am working is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # noqa
matplotlib.use ('TkAgg')

data = {'name': ['Reg 1', 'Reg 1', 'Reg 1','Reg 2', 'Reg 2','Reg 2','Reg 2',
                 'Reg 3','Reg 3','Reg 3','Reg 3','Reg 3','Reg 4','Reg 4',],
        'year': ['a', 'b', 'c','a','a','b','c',
                 'a','a','b','c','d','f','f'],
        'reports': ['ay', 'by', 'cy','ay','ay','ay','cy',
                 'ay','ay','by','dy','dy','ry','rx']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_occ=df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
ax = df_occ.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.show ()
```

Appreciate if someone can link to the appropriate reading material that I might miss.
Also, I am open to other library that can achieve the aforementioned objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
hatches = ['', '//']

bar_width = 0.45
names =set(df['name'])

for i, col in enumerate(['year','reports']):
    width = bar_width if i==0 else - bar_width
    s = pd.crosstab(df['name'], df[col])
    s.plot.bar(width=width, align='edge', stacked=True, ax=ax, edgecolor='w', hatch=hatches[i])
    
    for j, name in enumerate(names):
        ax.text(j + width/2, 0, col, ha='center')


    
xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xlim(xmin-0.4, xmax+0.5)
ax.legend(loc=[1.05, 0])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @quang, thanks and this is almost perfect. One trivial request if you can put label 'year' and 'reports' at each bar.